# Sonar C# plugin. Unable to parse files UTF-8 with BOM

Tags: c#, sonarqube, sonarqube-4.5

I have sonarqube 4.5.4 with installed C# plugin and it cant parse files in UTF-8 BOM encoding.

```
[15:08:01][Step 1/8] 16:07:06.847 ERROR - Unable to parse file: E:\BuildAgent\work\daac5e6d39eee3cb\Source\GraphVizGraph.cs
[15:08:01][Step 1/8] 16:07:06.847 ERROR - Parse error at line 1 column 0:
[15:08:01][Step 1/8]
[15:08:01][Step 1/8] --> п»їusing System;
```

Does anyone had this issue?

Comment: This exception is consistent with wrong encoding, is it perhaps some other encoding, sonar.sourceEncoding=Cp1252 ??

Comment: Encoding was not set in sonar.properties. I set tt to UTF-8. Result is same.    sonar.sourceEncoding=UTF-8

Answer (score 3):

I had to go through my files and change their encoding from utf-8 without bom using Notepad++.  The "Encoding" menu in the menubar at the top will give the ability to do this.

Comment: It is good solution but it does not give a guarantee that new UTF-8 with BIM files will appear in repository in a next few commits.

Answer (score 0):

As we using Teamcity, we found a python script wich deletes BOM From files.
We are running this script after checkout and before sonar steps. It removes bom from files and sonar works fine.

```
import os, re, sys

"""
    UTF-BOM Remover
    Usage: python bom.py [dir]
"""

bom = r"^\xEF\xBB\xBF"
pattern = r"^(.*)\.(php|js|css|txt|inc|conf|tpl|html|htm|cs|cpp|h|c|cxx)$"
cleaned_files = total_files = 0

if len(sys.argv) == 2:
    rundir = sys.argv[1]
else:
    rundir = '.'

if os.path.isdir(rundir):
    for root, dirs, files in os.walk(rundir):
        for name in files:
            if re.match(pattern, name):
                filename = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(root, name))
                buffer = open(filename, 'rb').read()
                file = re.search(bom, buffer)
                if file:
                    print "Remove BOM-marker from %s" % name
                    cleaned_files+= 1
                    open(filename, 'wb').write(buffer[:file.start()] + buffer[file.end():])
        total_files+= len(files)
    print "There are was %d files with BOM in %d files" % (cleaned_files, total_files)
else:
    print "Error: You must set a valid directory."
```